# ContextMenuStrip disappears after a quarter second display

Tags: treeview, contextmenustrip

Well, I'm back.  I solved the **ListBox** problem by using a **ContextMenuStrip** — *or so I thought!*

It comes in perfect, then in a quarter second, two things happen:  it *disappears*, and the **TreeNode** unselects.

But for that quarter second, it looks perfect!
[image]

The way that progresses is, I step through the lines of code on the right of the screenshot, 5 lines, then one more F11, and it appears for a 1/4 second, and the **TreeNode** *UNSELECTS*.

But here's another interesting thing:

In Design Mode, I clicked the reference to **contextMenuStrip1** in the dialog bar beneath the Form, and it appears in the place I dropped it.

[image]

Then a click on the **TreeView** (white as I suppose you know) and it disappears.

Ah, but then I take the mouse and pull the **TreeView** over to the right, again click the reference below, again the **ContextMenuStrip** appears, then I click the **TreeView**, and AGAIN it disappears!

[image]

What am I missing, dear friends? Something to do with the focus?

Much obliged for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  I found that responding to Closing could be stopped for study with a break point.  Then poked around in the Properties, and tried a few things.  Then ultimately googled and found the answer at
[Do not close ContextMenuStrip on selection of certain items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866689/do-not-close-contextmenustrip-on-selection-of-certain-items).  I added AppFocusChange as not a reason to close.

So far, I'm now able to click the members and select them. Progress!

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.AppClicked || 
            e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.AppFocusChange)
                e.Cancel = true;
    }
     if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (contextMenuStrip1.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    bool res = DoChoice(i);
                    if (res == true) e.Cancel = false;


                }
            }
        }
```

Then, at DoChoice, I'll invoke the Add or Edit accordingly, and always returna Close to the strip.